# Firefox won't remember passwords, and throws weird javascript exceptions

Tags: firefox, password-management

Two days ago Firefox started throwing strange javascript errors
e.g.

```
Error: Cc[contractID] is undefined
Source File: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/components/nsLoginManager.js
Line: 113
```

It's throwing these on every page on every site I visit.

If I browse to a site that requires http authentication (e.g. http://seo.dizzyheights.com - one of our test sites), the authentication dialog no longer includes the "Remember this password" checkbox, even though I'm not in Private Browsing mode, and "Remember passwords for sites" is still ticked in the Firefox options. It also throws an even bigger javascript error:

```
Error: LoginManagerPrompter: Epic fail in promptAuth: [Exception... "'[JavaScript Error: "Cc[contractID] is undefined" {file: "file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/components/nsLoginManager.js" line: 113}]' when calling method: [nsILoginManager::findLogins]"  nsresult: "0x80570021 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JAVASCRIPT_ERROR_WITH_DETAILS)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/components/nsLoginManagerPrompter.js :: anonymous :: line 585"  data: yes]

Source File: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/components/nsLoginManagerPrompter.js
Line: 607
```

If I view saved passwords in the Firefox options dialog, there are none.

I've deleted my key3.db and signons.sqlite files from my profile, but that didn't help.

These errors continue if I run Firefox in safe mode, so I don't think it's related to any of my add-ons. I'm running Firefox 3.6.6 on Vista SP2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your FF installation is simply corrupt. Have you tried reinstalling FF? This will leave your profile folders untouched, so no settings should be lost (you only need to reinstall addons that were installed for everyone).

If you are curious, you could also backup your old files under Program Files/Mozilla, and compare them after the reinstall.

Comment: Thanks sleske - that's done it. Note to self: try the simple fixes first! I wonder what could have happened to corrupt it like that?